# Show that exist subset U and V of Metric Space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space, let be $x_0 \in X$, such that $x_0 \notin A$, where A is a subset closed of $X$. Show that exist open subset U and V disjoints of $X$ , such that $x_0 \in U$ and $A \subset V$.

My attemp, Obviously I can take to open ball of center $ x_0 $ and radius $ r > $ 0 , $ U = B ( x_0 , r) \ subset X $, but what's happens With $ A \ subset V $ ?, or exist to better approach to the solutions .. anyway , some hint for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

***HINTS:*** $A$ is closed so $A^c$ is open...so there exists $\delta >0$ s.t $B(x_0, \delta) \cap A = \phi$ (since $x_0$ is a interior point)...consider $U= B(x_0,\delta /2)$ and $V= \cup_{a \in A} B(a,\delta/2)$ since arbitraty union of open set is open...

Comment: but something was not entirely clear , the intersection is always empty?

Comment: Try to think if it is not empty then what wrong will happen